# Finding out if page is rotated in a PDF

Tags: pdf

Is there a reliable way to determine if a given page in a PDF file is upside down? I have documents where occasionally a page will be rotated 180 degrees, it is easy to fix once you know which pages are rotated, but is there a way to find out a process them automatically?

One of the issues is that the page is not OCR'd, it always appears to be with no rotation (iTextSharp returns 0 degrees to all), it is only after OCR'ing that Adobe for example rearranges the pages. However this is an interactive process and I would like to streamline it.

Comment: This is one of those things where a human can recognize upside down with a glance.  Just quickly scrolling through the document might be the fastest, simplest solution.

Comment: I agree; however that's not an option when you have thousands of such files to process..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify flipped (rotated 180°) pages in PDF file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1313819/how-to-identify-flipped-rotated-180-pages-in-pdf-file)