# How to identify flipped (rotated 180°) pages in PDF file?

Tags: macos, pdf, automation, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader

I have thousands of PDF files. Our kind hearted person who scanned them all into existence must have gone glazed over at some point, because some selection of pages were scanned upside down.

I've calculated that to manually review all of these pages will take in the realm of 12 hours. This does not factor in correction (there is also a digital label affixed right side up, bonus points if you can figure out how to maintain that!).

Any help or notion of which direction to search would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the page contains text that Acrobat's OCR can understand, you may be able to get away with using the "Recognize Text" feature, as I learned [from this link](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1236207).

From the last post on that page:

> In Acrobat X I can use Tools/Recognize Text/ Aa In This File which will deskew and process page(s) for OCR, i.e. make it a searchable document.  When I do this on a multiple manually scanned document which has pages upside down,
>   the deskew rotates them 180 degrees, that is corrects the manual scan orientation.

Comment: 10/10 for simple solution. Will report back if this actually works (even if it is slow as all heck).

Comment: Confirmed this does work on my sample - which is full of noise and numbers, handwriting. It unfortunately doesn't recognize text that is already right side up and maintain it, even if that text was applied via Adobe bates numbering. However, for the question I asked, this fills the req 100%.

Comment: Aw bummer it doesn't work fully. Hopefully this saves you some effort!